# PHP preg_split alpha numeric mixed string then make alpha key

Tags: php

I have a string:  `a74b8c0d3845e7`… etc etc.

The basic pattern is a letter followed by a number.

I want to create an array that would result in:

```
Array (
[a] => 74
[b] => 8
[c] => 0
[d] => 3845
[e] => 7
)
```

I know it'll be a foreach loop (or a couple) but just can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: I think you need to split the string into individual characters and compile if it manually..

Comment: Lol looks like everyone is fighting for that checkmark. You've got several working algorithms here ... now you have to chose your favorite :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `preg_split`, you can use `preg_match_all` to get all the letters and corresponding numbers.

```
preg_match_all('/([a-z])(\d+)/', $string, $match);
$result = array();
foreach ($match[1] as $i => $letter) {
  $result[$letter] = $match[2][$i];
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I gotta give the green check to this one.  Thanks to everyone for such quick responses!

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = "a74b8c0d3845e7";
$letters = preg_split("/[0-9]+/",$str);
$nums = preg_split("/[a-z]+/", $str);
array_shift($nums);
array_pop($letters);
print_r(array_combine($letters,$nums));
```

prints out

```
Array
(
    [a] => 74
    [b] => 8
    [c] => 0
    [d] => 3845
    [e] => 7
)
```

Comment: I try this and actually nothing prints out.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into using [`str_split`](http://us.php.net/str_split) which would split your string into an array that can be iterated over. Here is an example I just threw together:

```
// Set the string value.
$string = 'a74b8c0d3845e7';

// Create the string array using `str_split`.
$string_array = str_split($string);

// Init `$final_array`.
$final_array = array();

// Roll throgh the `$string_array` using `foreach`.
foreach ($string_array as $string_key => $string_value) {
  // If the value `is_numeric` assign it as `$final_value`.
  // Else set the `$final_key` & reset the `$final_value`.
  if (is_numeric($string_value)) {
    $final_value = $string_value;
  }
  else {
    $final_key = $string_value;
    $final_value = '';
  }
  // Set the value in the `$final_array`.
  $final_array[$final_key] .= $final_value;
}

// Dump the `$final_array` to show the concept works.
echo '<pre>';
print_r($final_array);
echo '</pre>';
```

The output is:

```
Array
(
    [a] => 74
    [b] => 8
    [c] => 0
    [d] => 3845
    [e] => 7
)
```

Comment: `str_split` splits it into equal-length blocks.  How does that help here?

Comment: You're just iterating over the characters in the string. You don't need to use `str_split` for that, just a normal `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
$str = 'a74b8c0d3845e7';

$arr = preg_split('/[a-zA-Z]+/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
$no_num = preg_replace('/[0-9]/', '', $str);

$new_arr = array();

foreach ($arr as $i=>$a)
    $new_arr[$no_num[$i]] = $a;

print_r($new_arr);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [a] => 74
    [b] => 8
    [c] => 0
    [d] => 3845
    [e] => 7
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. How it works is it makes 2 arrays. The first array is split by letters, making an array of numbers. Then the next array is split by numbers, making an array of letters. Finally the two arrays are combined into a new array with the letter as its key and a number as its value! Pretty neat...

```
    $string = 'a74b8c0d3845e7';

    $array1 = preg_split("/[a-zA-Z]+/", $string);
    $array2 = preg_split("/[0-9]+/", $string);

    for($i = 1; $i <= count($array1); $i++) {
        if(isset($array1[$i])){
            $newarray[$array2[$i-1]] = $array1[$i];
        }
    }

    var_dump($newarray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$a = "a74b8c0d3845e7";
preg_match_all("/[\d]+/", $a, $numbers);
preg_match_all("/[a-z]+/i", $a, $strings);
$c=array_combine($strings[0],$numbers[0]);
print_r($c);
```

Check it [here](http://3v4l.org/mQBLo).

Comment: I try this and actually nothing prints out.

Comment: its working check it out [here](http://3v4l.org/mQBLo) Hopefully You are using PHP v5+

Comment: The error will occur when the string ends with an char because the length of each array will differ

Comment: I had a trailing "Z" in my real code, hence the mistake on my end.